# wordpress child pages are highlighted in submenu

Tags: css, wordpress

In the parent page, when I mouse over the menubar button for that page, all of its child pages are highlighted in the dropdown. How do I fix this?

http://www.captainpoolservice.com/swimming-pool-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
.main-menu .current-menu-item ul li a {
    background: #ddd !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-shadow: #fff 1px 1px;
}

.main-menu .current-menu-item ul li a:hover {
    background: #010187 !important;
    color: white !important;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px;
}
```